# C function declaration returning pointer to specific sized array

Tags: c

I have been playing around with C function declarations/definitions and came up with these.

Is there a reason why `g1` would be preferred over `g2`, other than wanting to return a pointer to a specific sized array?
Is there a better way to write `g1` (with typedefs? etc.)?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char (*g1(int dummy))[10]
{
 char (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof *p);
 return p;
}

char * g2(int dummy)
{
 char (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof *p);
 return (void *)p;
}

int main()
{
  g1(10);
  g2(20);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a suspicion about the validity of `g1` definition...

Comment: g1 is a ```function that takes an int and returns a pointer to an array of size 10 chars```

Comment: Holly code... have never seen one like this and I don't want to see it again. So it is not preferred for me for sure. But probably good for some typechecking.

Comment: Yes, I was just as shocked as you when I've found out about it! But it is valid so I need to know

Comment: @Seoul _"But it is valid so I need to know"_ only for silly work interview I think. Completely useless in "normal" programming. Barely readable, easy to make silly mistakes.

Comment: "Is there a better way to write"? --> The cast in `return (void *)p;` is a hint that code is suspect.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, `g1` returns a pointer to an array of `char` containing exactly 10 elements, whereas `g2` returns a pointer to a single `char`, which would allow for a `char` array of any length following it in memory.

Seeing as C will not enforce the bounds of an array, the only advantage I can see with `g1` over `g2` is the ability to specify a size when assigning a variable, just as you have mentioned.

If you wanted to rewrite `g1` using a `typedef`, you could use the following:

```
typedef char (*char_array_t)[10];

char_array_t g1(int dummy)
{
 char_array_t p = malloc(sizeof *p);
 return p;
}
```

Comment: `typedef char (*char_array_t)[10];` masks that the type is a pointer. See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

`g1` is more "correct" since it accurately reflects the type of the object you are returning (pointer to 10-element array of `char`).  You don't normally see functions that return pointers to arrays, since the array size must be fixed at compile time, limiting its usefulness, and most of us subconsciously avoid writing code like that because it's just too damned eye-stabby.  If I were writing a function that allocated a 2D array, I'd usually write it as

```
void g1( size_t rows, size_t cols, char (**p)[cols] )
{
  *p = malloc( sizeof **p * rows );
}

int main( void )
{
  char (*table)[10];
  g1( 5, 10, &table );
  if ( table )
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

which allows me to take advantage of VLA semantics (in C99 or later), making it flexible without being *excessively* ugly.

You *can* typedef some of the ugliness away:

```
typedef char MyType[10];

MyType *g1( int dummy );
{
  MyType *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
  ...
  return p;
}
```

but I'm leary of using `typedef`s just to make the code scan better.  You should only `typedef` a type for *abstraction* purposes (i.e., to hide the implementation from the user of the type).  If the user of the type needs to be aware of the "array-ness" of the type, then do *not* hide it behind a `typedef`.

I don't like `g2` because it *lies*.  `p` is not a `char *`, it's a `char (*)[10]`.  That *matters*.

Comment: UV for good answer (except that 2D part - no 2D array in code).

Comment: @chux: mine or the OP's?  No, the OP didn't create a 2D array, but IME there's almost never a reason to create a pointer to an array unless you're allocating a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to write?

If the function needs to return "a pointer to an array of size 10 chars" then `g1()` is fine.  It meets the design goal.

```
char (*g1(int dummy))[10] {
 char (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof *p);
 return p;
}
```

If the function needs to return "a pointer to 10 chars" then use

```
char *allocate10char(int dummy) {
 char *p  = malloc(sizeof *p * 10);
 return p;
}
```

If `char (*g1(int dummy))[10]` is too strange, then the coding goal needs to imporve.

`